# My favorite questions need to be classified!

Tags: discussion, bookmarks

It is frequently happens to me while I am online here at Mathematics SE to favorite a nice question. Now, after a year, I see my favorite questions need to be classified. Is there any way for users here to categorize their favorite questions (For example by labeling them ) or even their own questions in an appropriate way?

I am asking kindly here because I don't know if it's asked before.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. You should use instead your browser's bookmark feature for that, or possibly a social bookmark site like http://delicious.com/

Comment: There used to be a "search within favourites" advanced search option, but it has been [disabled due to performance concerns](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78946/155238). But note that its reimplementation is something that they will work on. If that feature were reimplemented, you'd be able to filter you favorites using question tags.

Comment: Related question: [Managing favourites](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3639/managing-favourites).

Comment: I save questions on [Pinboard](https://pinboard.in/), but of course you do need to retag things. It would definitely be nice if someone wrote a bookmarklet that copied tags from here to Pinboard when saving a page.

Comment: @BenedictEastaugh: Thank you Benedict. Thank you Martin and dear Willie. :)

Comment: Lol, I understood that you want to make them top secret! :-P

Comment: @dtldarek: :-))))

Comment: @WillieWong 's first comment gives a good solution.